# R Markdown Presentation not loading/ rendering interactive Plotly chart

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I am using [**Plotly with R**](https://plot.ly/r/) to create a chart that will be rendered in a [R Markdown Presentation With Ioslides](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html), but instead of showing [the demo chart from the website](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/) like the following:

[image]

It is rendering the steps like this:

[image]

My code is pretty simple:

````
---
title: "R Markdown Presentation & Plotly"
author: "Eduardo Almeida"
date: "February 19, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Interactive plot with Plotly 

```{r}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop)
```
````

Comment: Use `suppressPackageStartupMessages({library(plotly)})` to avoid package messages. Then type a `p` in the last line of your code to display the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karthik Arumugham pointed out you need to display the plot, either by entering `p` or not assigning `plot_ly` to variable but calling it directly.

I'd suggest to explicitly state the missing variables (`type='scatter', mode='markers'`) instead of suppressing the output messages. In addition you could add `{r, warning=F}` to get rid of the

> Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

message.

````
---
title: "R Markdown Presentation & Plotly"
author: "Eduardo Almeida"
date: "February 19, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Interactive plot with Plotly 

```{r, warning=F}
suppressPackageStartupMessages({library(plotly)})
library(plotly)
plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop, type='scatter', mode='markers')
```
````

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. It's still shoing the same message as in the second image.

Comment: Did you add suppressPackageStartupMessages({library(plotly)}) before the importing plotly?